# Property 'width' does not exist on type 'StyleProp<ViewStyle>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I am working on a React Native app built with TypeScript. I have a component which uses the same props as a `View` element. If there is a `style` prop, I need to pull the `width` in order to pass a calculated width to a child. A simplified example might look like this.

```
const WidgetContainer = ({ style = {}, ...props }: ViewProps) => {
    const { width = DEFAULT_WIDTH } = style;
    const widgetWidth = Math.floor(width / 3);

    return (
        <View style={[style, { width }]} {...props}>
            <WidgetRow widgetWidth={widgetWidth} />
        </View>
    );
};
```

Everything uses absolute positioning and we can safely assume only numeric widths will be used. This should work. Expo runs the code just fine and nothing seems amiss.

But if I explicitly do a type check, either in VS Code or by running `tsc`, I get this error on the second line:

```
Property 'width' does not exist on type 'StyleProp<ViewStyle>'
```

This is frankly baffling. I use `width` in View styles all over the code base. If I look up the declaration file for `react-native` types, I can see `ViewStyle`:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-native/index.d.ts#L1963

It *extends* `FlexStyle`:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-native/index.d.ts#L692

And `width` is right there!!

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-native/index.d.ts#L743

I am at a loss. Is this a bug? Am I missing something silly?

Relevant versions:

- react: 17.0.38
- react-native: 0.64.3
- tsc: 4.3.5
- node_modules/expo: 44.0.6
- expo CLI: 5.4.9

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how is `ViewProps` defined?

Comment: `ViewProps` comes from React Native. It types `style` as `StyleProps<ViewStyle> | undefined`. You can see it in that same declaration file:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-native/index.d.ts#L2381